# Does the Lebesgue measure of $[0,\infty)^n\setminus[0,a)$ approach $0$ as $a\to\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure; for each $a>0$, let $A_a:=[0,\infty)^n\setminus[0,a)^n$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is arbitrarily fixed. Is it true that $\lim\limits_{a\to\infty} \lambda(A_a)=0?$

Comment: $\lambda(A_a)=\infty$ for all $a$, so no, it doesn't tends to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. For instance if $n = 1$, then $A_a = [0, \infty) \setminus [0, a) = [a, \infty)$.

And since for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $\lambda\left(\left[a, \infty\right)\right) = \infty$, then
$$\lim_{a \to \infty}\lambda\left(\left[a, \infty\right)\right) = \infty$$

Comment: Thanks @JamieAlizadeh! That makes sense I presume this argument still holds for $n\in\{2,3,...\}$? (That was *actually* what I had in mind, but I just wrote "$n\in\mathbb{N}$" since it's more standard  Apologies!)

Comment: Yes it does. For fixed $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$,  
$$\lambda([a, \infty)^n \setminus [0,a)^n ) =  \lambda([a, \infty)^n) - \lambda([0,a)^n ) = \infty - a^n = \infty$$
where the first equality holds by disjointness. So for whichever $n$ you choose you'll always get a sequence of $\infty$'s as $a \to \infty$.